# Regarding proxy in python requests

Tags: python, python-requests

Suppose, I have declared a **global** variable as below in one of my python packages authored by me:

```
proxyDict = {
    "http": os.environ["http_proxy"],
    "https": os.environ["https_proxy"]
}
```

The package is build and deployed to the CICD pipeline, will it impact the deployment server in any way ? Further, will `http_proxy` environment variable be impacted in any way on the server where the packages are deployed (and services like `celery` are running) ? (as a side note, all the servers are linux). Will it actually be safer to keep the declaration as **local** to a function ?